# Swiper keyboard custom keys

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, swiper.js

I have a horizontal Swiper and keyboard enabled, which means I can swipe using left and right keys. But I want to be able to swipe using top and bottom keys as well. I wrote this script, but it doesn't work, does anyone have an idea why?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    slidesPerView: 1,
    speed: 600,
    effect: 'fade',
    keyboard: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  });

  swiper.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key == 38) {
      swiper.slidePrev();
    }
    if (e.key == 40) {
      swiper.slideNext();
    }
  });

});
```

I also read this documentation, maybe this is the easier way to assign custom keys, but I have no idea how to use it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `keyPress` event with `swiper.on` method, like it's described [here](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events)

Example:

```
swiper.on("keyPress", (swiper, keyCode) => {
  switch (keyCode) {
    case 38:
      swiper.slidePrev();
      break;
    case 40:
      swiper.slideNext();
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! It works like a charm. Just one more question, is it possible to do the same for touch events? Currently, I can change slides by swiping left and right, but I want to be able to do the same by swiping up and down.

Comment: I think you can try to subscribe  to `touchMoveOpposite` or `touchMove` event in the same way - `swiper.on('touchMoveOpposite', (swiper, event) =>`. But I didn't test it tbh.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same but never mind, thank you!